# Starting with Hall effect sensor

Tags: sensor, hall-effect

I have been playing around with a ASC758 in a PSS Leadform package. After reading the [datasheet](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Part_Numbers/0758/0758.pdf) I am still thoroughly confused. Can someone please help me understand this sensor.

What I am confused about is how to connect the sensor in the first place (weather or not to put the wire that I am sensing in between the terminals, or to connect it to them).

I am also getting approximately 1.6v when the sensor is not connected to anything. I know this has a bi-directional and uni-directional setup, but I cant figure out how to configure the sensor for either setup. It would appear from this voltage that the sensor is in bi-directional setup.

My last issue is that I am not sure of the equation to calculate the amperage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The measured current **has** to flow **through** the package to produce any result.

Therefore, you have to **cut** the wire, and solder one end to one of the terminals, and the other end to the other terminal.

The nominal output is 1/2 Vcc, assuming you are using the birirectional variant. The datasheet states:

<sub>**Datasheet, page 15**</sub>

> **Quiescent output voltage (V<sub>IOUT(Q)</sub>).** The output of the device  when
>   the primary current is zero. For bidirectional devices,  it nominally
>   remains at VCC ⁄ 2.  Thus, VCC = 5 V translates  into V<sub>IOUT(QBI)</sub> = 2.5
>   V. For unidirectional devices, it nomi- nally remains at 0.1 × VCC. 
>   Thus, VCC = 5 V translates into  V<sub>IOUT(QUNI)</sub> = 0.5 V.  Variation in
>   V<sub>IOUT(Q)</sub> can be attributed to  the resolution of the Allegro linear IC
>   quiescent voltage trim,  magnetic hysteresis, and thermal drift.

<sub><sup>QUNI means Quiescent (e.g. no current flow), unidirectional variant. QBI means Quiescent, Bi-Directional variant. V<sub>IOUT</sub> is the name of the output pin. See the pinout on page 1.</sup></sub>

Since you say you are getting ~1.6V, I would guess you're using the bidirectional variant, and powering it from 3.3V.

---

I don't know how you're having trouble figuring out the current, it's very simple:

<sub>**Datasheet, page 15**</sub>

> **Sensitivity (Sens).** The change in device output in response to a  1 A
>   change through the primary conductor. The sensitivity is the  product
>   of the magnetic circuit sensitivity (G / A) and the linear  IC
>   amplifier gain (mV/G). The linear IC amplifier gain is pro- grammed at
>   the factory to optimize the sensitivity (mV/A) for the  half-scale
>   current of the device.

There are multiple versions, with different sensitivity.

From page 2 of the datasheet:
[image]

The sensitivity is given in mV/A. Therefore, with a device with a 40mV/A sensitivity, 1A of current through the device will result in the output voltage increasing by 40mV.

The overall equation is:

$$V_{IOUT} = ( Vcc * OffsetScaling ) + ( Scaling Factor In Volts * Amps ) $$

\$OffsetScaling\$:

- Bidirectional version = 0.5
- Unidirectional version = 0.1

\$Scaling Factor In Volts\$:

- This is the scaling factor given in the above table, converted to volts.

Therefore, for the bi-directional variant, with 40mv/A sensitivity, the output voltage will be:
$$V_{IOUT} = Vcc*0.5+ 0.040 * A$$
The uni-directional variant with 40mv/A sensitivity would be:
$$V_{IOUT} = Vcc* 0.1 + 0.040 * A$$

<sup><sub>0.040 is 40mV in Volts. Change to match your device sensitivity.</sub></sup>

Comment: So is the equation ((Vout - (VCC/2))*(.1*VCC))Amps? The paragraph from the datasheet does not make a whole lot of since. And by through you mean connected to both terminals, right?

Comment: @Reid - see edits. I was not done.